# How do I change the colouring of preprocesor #if'd code in a Xamarin project in Visual Studio 2015?

Tags: xamarin, visual-studio-2015, color-scheme

I am using a Xamarin solution (VS2015), with shared code then a separate project for UWP, IOS and Android.

In the shared project, how do I change which code is greyed out when using `#if`?

e.g:

```
#if (WINDOWS_PHONE || WINDOWS_UWP || WINDOWS_APP)
    StorageFolder storageFolder = Windows.Storage.ApplicationData.Current.LocalFolder;
    StorageFile sampleFile = await storageFolder.GetFileAsync(fileName);
    string text = await FileIO.ReadTextAsync(sampleFile);
    return text;
#elif (__IOS__ || __ANDROID__)
    var documentsPath = Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.Personal);
    var filePath = Path.Combine(documentsPath, fileName);
    return await Task.Run(() => File.ReadAllText(filePath));
#endif
```

Currently the `__ANDROID__` section is being colourised by VS, and the WINDOWS_PHONE part is greyed out. How can I tell VS that I want it the other way around?

Comment: It has highlighted the Android/iOS section of code since that is the current code path based upon the active project. Set the startup project to WinPhone/UWP/WPF and the other code path will be evaluated.

Comment: I have set the active project to UWP, but that didn't make a difference. That was my initial assumption, too.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Drop down this box and select the appropriate project to run, in your case, the UWP project [image]

Comment: Ok, I just actually tried it, and same deal, in both Shared project and PCL.

I think there is some problem with the symbol not being defined in the project where the code is sitting. If you move that code to say the UWP project, you will see the colouring moves. But that is not helpful.

Comment: yes, so I guess the question is (for you or anyone else reading this) - can we define the symbol for the Shared project?

Comment: This might be a missing feature/bug in Visual Studio, as it should pass the symbol from the project set to deploy in configuration manager.